# Exception in queued GPT command TypeError: googletag.SizeMapping is not a function

Tags: wordpress, google-ad-manager

I'm trying to display ads on my test website before I use it for my live site.

I've placed the generated code from Admanager in the head and in the body of de webpage. The ad is showing fine, but when I resize my screen, the same ad is showing up on tablet and mobile. I've set different ads by using Sizemapping, and it's giving me this error in the chrome inspector:

Exception in queued GPT command TypeError: googletag.SizeMapping is not a function
    at Arguments. ((index):70)
    at Gk.push (pubads_impl_modern_2019112101.js?21065216:1)
    at Nk (pubads_impl_modern_2019112101.js?21065216:1)
    at pubads_impl_modern_2019112101.js?21065216:1
    at dq (pubads_impl_modern_2019112101.js?21065216:1)
    at pubads_impl_modern_2019112101.js?21065216:1
    at pubads_impl_modern_2019112101.js?21065216:1

How can I fix this?

This is the code in my head:

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-5630600850555485" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script async src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
<script>
  window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
  googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot('/10643240/test_aanhetbouwen', [[300, 600], [300, 250], [728, 90], [970, 250], [320, 100]], 'div-gpt-ad-4873663-1').addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.enableServices();
  });
</script>
<!-- Start GPT Tag -->
<script async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
<script>
 var gptadslots = [];
 var googletag = googletag || {cmd:[]};
</script>
<script>
 googletag.cmd.push(function() {
  var mapping1 = googletag.SizeMapping()
              .addSize([1024, 770], [[300, 600]])
              .addSize([770, 400], [[300, 250]])
              .addSize([1, 1], [[300, 250]])
              .build();
  //Adslot 1 declaration
  gptadslots.push(googletag.defineSlot('/10643240/test_aanhetbouwen', [[300,250],[300,600]], 'div-gpt-ad-4873663-1')
               .defineSizeMapping(mapping1)
               .addService(googletag.pubads()));
  googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
  googletag.enableServices();
 });
</script>
<!-- End GPT Tag -->
```

And this is my code in the body:

```
<!-- GPT AdSlot 1 for Ad unit 'test_aanhetbouwen' ### Size: [[300,600]] -->
<div id="div-gpt-ad-4873663-1">
  <script>
    googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-4873663-1'); });
  </script>
</div>
<!-- End AdSlot 1 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable Adblock or any other advert-blocker.